# Android DialogFragment inner LinearLayout returning null

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-dialogfragment

I am currently working on an app that requires a custom dialog fragment. The dialog is composed of two elements, a message and an image OR a circular progress bar view. For the image/progressbar I am using a linearlayout as a container that I want to retain a reference to and dynamically add image/progressbar view during runtime.

Problem: I can find the reference to the textview, however when I try to get a reference to the inner linearlayout it returns null. I have also tried to inflate parent layout and retain reference to it as rootview and then try rootview.findViewById() with no success.

Odd: I am easily able to find the reference to the inner TextView, only linearlayout returns null.

Would really appreciate some guidance on this problem, seems like something very simple but for the life of me I can't figure out why it's returning null. I have posted the code below.

```
package com.app.devicetest.dialogs;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.app.devicetest.R;

public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

    public final static int STYLE_SUCCESS = 1;
    public final static int STYLE_FAILURE = 2;
    public final static int STYLE_PROGRESS = 3;

    private String message;
    private TextView dialogMessage;
    private LinearLayout dialogImageLayout;

//    private LinearLayout rootView;

    private Context mContext;

    public CustomDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public CustomDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        mContext = context;
    }

    protected CustomDialog(Context context, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// NOTE: I have also tried using this method with rootView.findViewById but the inner linearlayout still returns null.
//        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//        rootView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom, null);

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_custom);

        dialogMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogMessage);
        dialogMessage.setText(message);

        dialogImageLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dialogImageLayout);

        setCancelable(true);
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    }


    public void setDialogMessage(String msg) {
        message = msg;
    }

    public void dialogStyle(int style) {
        // Note: Always returns null here.
        Log.i("dialog", "dialog reference : " + ((dialogImageLayout == null) ? "null" : "not null"));


        if(style == STYLE_SUCCESS) {
        }
        else if(style == STYLE_FAILURE) {
        }
        else if(style == STYLE_PROGRESS) {

        }
    }
}
```

Below is the layout file: dialog_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_dialog_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/dialogImageLayout">

        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:id="@+id/dialogMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code for calling the dialog:

```
    completeDialog = new CustomDialog(mContext, R.style.Theme_CustomDialog);
    completeDialog.dialogStyle(CustomDialog.STYLE_SUCCESS);
    completeDialog.setDialogMessage("Operation successfully completed.");
    completeDialog.show();
```

Comment: Try extending `DialogFragment` instead and override `onCreateView()`.

Comment: awkward, have you tried cleaning your project and rebuilding it?

Comment: I have already tried extending Dialog and used onCreateView() I was thinking that the layout may have not been inflated by the time I was getting the reference. Again, that makes less sense since I am able to get a reference to TextView.

Also tried cleaning and rebuilding several times :) 
I am using Nexus 7 to test this code.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was worth mentioning how I overcame this problem for people who also run into this error.

After some much research I figured out the reason why this is happening. It seems the method dialogStyle() is called before the inner view has a chance to inflate (probably due to the fact that it takes longer to inflate the view, compared to TextView). If you do a log print on onCreateView on dialogImageLayout, you will notice that the reference is NOT NULL.

Therefore it is probably best to hold reference variable to the current style inside the class when the user calls dialogStyle() and add view inside the dialog class when you know the view is properly inflated and you have a reference to it.